# Is there a way I can increment the column reference while going down a single column?

Tags: excel, excel-2010, counting

So I have a range that is B2:B20.  In this range I have strings, which include, 'I strongly agree,' 'I strongly disagree,' etc. I have multiple columns with each representing a question and which answer was given. I want to count the amount of each occurrence in B2:B20, C2:C20, etc and display them by dragging down a column.  Photos are provided below since this is difficult to word.

[image]

[image]

Basically, I want to count how many of each response each question got (columns in Figure 1) in Figure 2.  Ie. in Figure 2, Q1-Strongly agree counts the strongly agrees in Figure 1 column 1. Q2-Strongly agree counts the strongly agrees in Figure 1 column 2. Q3-strongly agree counts the strongly agrees in Figure 1 column 3.  I hope this isn't too confusing.  Thanks for your guys' time.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
=COUNIFS(INDEX($B$2:$T$20,,ROW($ZZ1)),"*"&U$1&"*")
```

Where `$B$2:$T$20` are the data columns and `U$1` is the cell with `Strongly Agree` in the output.

Comment: Thank you for your response! Is it ok if you explain your syntax a little?